# Why does `MemberShip.GetUser()` return null while `User.IsAuthenticated` returns true and the Username information is available in the database?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, mono, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

A Debian server is running a MVC4 app on Mono which uses a Membership ASPSqlProvider. The application has a method `GetUserIdByName` which creates a link between the `Users` table in the Membership database and the non-Membership `Users` table `Users` user's ID.

On my local Linux Mint system this setup does not have problem, but when the application is put on the Debian host (with the same XSP4 server and same version of Mono) and visited via the web it happens that `MemberShip.GetUser()` returns null. I found that out by wrapping the code in try-catch blocks and reading the exception from the website:

```
public int GetCurrentUserId()
{
    var userName = "";
    var currentUserName = "test";

    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) 
    {
        try 
        {
            userName = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
            currentUserName = Membership.GetUser().UserName;
        } 
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message + " User is:" + userName);
        }
    }

    var currentUserId = _repository.GetUserIdByUserName(currentUserName);

    return currentUserId;
}
```

The exception raised reads something like

> NullReferenceException User is:theusersemailaddress@gmail.com

Interestingly enough when I query the database I see that the `Username` is there in the Membership `Users` table.

A solution is to just use the users email and change the method to `GetUserIdByEmail` which I will do for now. Someone who provided this solution in another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575358/membership-getuser-is-returning-null-when-app-starts#12594511) got told that this was not a real solution but a workaround, and I agree.

So the question remains: why does on the Debian machine `MemberShip.GetUser()` return null while `User.IsAuthenticated` returns true and the Username information is available in the database?

/Edit, I see now that `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` returns the `Email` column on the Debian machine, and the `Username` column on the Linux mint one. Why would that be?

Comment: Are they using the exact same Mono framework version/source? Are both environments properly configured to use Forms Authentication? For that matter, is any other configuration different?

Comment: @Colin Indeed the same Mono version and same web.config file.

Comment: Hi @ErwinRooijakkers did you ever find a solution for this? Thanks

Comment: @refex I ended up using `GetUserIdByEmail`. It's a long time ago but from an online search it seems that `Membership.GetUser()` gets its data from an auth cookie, not the  database. And I see from the source that there's also an overload (https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Web/Security/Membership.cs#L199), which has the signature `GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)` with default `true` for `userIsOnline`, so maybe the user is not online and `MemberShip.GetUser(username, false)` works.